# Meteor 1.3 import npm module issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, package

This seems simple enough but can't seem work it out following the guide for using npm [using Npm packages Meteor 1.3](http://guide.meteor.com/using-packages.html)
I meteor install the moment npm module.

Then when i try to use the package in the client I keep getting.

```
import moment from 'moment';
var Moment = require('moment')()

Template.myTemp.events({
'click #exampleBtn': function(e){

e.preventdefault()

console.log(Moment)

  }
});
```

In the console I seem to be getting
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module.
ReferenceError: moment is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already `import moment from 'moment'`, you don't need line #2. Essentially, line #1 and line #2 are the same.

Line #1 is ES2015 module syntax.
Line #2 is CommonJS module syntax.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for that I removed it but still seem to be getting  SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module in the console and no  log of moment

Comment: Since you import momentjs as lowercase moment, can you try `console.log(moment().calendar())`?

Comment: Thanks that did it